# Text layout framework for iOS

Tags: ios, layout, frameworks, typography

Aside from Webviews, are there any text layout frameworks on iOS for custom views?
OpenGL could work fine aswell as something `UIView`-based.

Think Metro UI-ish, and I'd really enjoy templates and some sort of adaptive capabilities for landscape, portrait, ipad vs iphone, etc.

Comment: NSView? Are you targeting iOS or OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreText.framework would be a good starting point. It's a 'Core' framework, which integrates well with CoreGraphics. If you want UIView-centric rendering, prepare to write some wrappers.

A high level alternative to CoreText.framework would be to use `NSAttributedString` in `UITextView`s (ios6 or greater).

Here's the high level overview:

> Core Text provides a modern, low-level programming
>   interface for laying out text and handling fonts. The Core Text layout
>   engine is designed for high performance, ease of use, and close
>   integration with Core Foundation. The text layout API provides
>   high-quality typesetting, including character-to-glyph conversion,
>   with ligatures, kerning, and so on. The complementary Core Text font
>   technology provides automatic font substitution (cascading), font
>   descriptors and collections, easy access to font metrics and glyph
>   data, and many other features.
>
> Multicore Considerations: All individual functions in Core Text are
>   thread safe. Font objects (CTFont, CTFontDescriptor, and associated
>   objects) can be used by simultaneously by multiple operations, work
>   queues, or threads. However, the layout objects (CTTypesetter,
>   CTFramesetter, CTRun, CTLine, CTFrame, and associated objects) should
>   be used in a single operation, work queue, or thread.

Comment: From a quick glance it was my assumption that CoreText only does very basic layout, but maybe I should give it a second look.

Comment: @PBeck if you look into CoreText further (the examples too), you will see it provides low level primitives for layout and rendering. in a way, that collection of primitives may appear "basic", but that fine level of control/flexibility allows you to accomplish many complex text rendering tasks. also consider it as an extension to CoreGraphics -- consider how you would integrate it with CoreGraphics rendering for transformations and stylization. one could write a complex word processor type app using CoreText and CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 0):

Check out DTRichTextEditor by Cocoanetics. They offer the free DTCoreText that I've used for over a year now with great success (to display HTML and rich text). [This is one link I just found](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/dtrichtexteditor-dtcoretext-news/) but you can just look at the [Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com) site too (DTCoreText is free, the editor has a cost to it).